# Do unlocked Monster List entries get reset when using Earlier Times in battle?

Tags: super-mario-rpg-2023

When Mallow uses Thought Peak on an enemy and reads their though it completes the enemy's [Monster List](https://www.mariowiki.com/Monster_List) entry and marks it with a green checkmark. There is also an item [Earlier Times](https://www.mariowiki.com/Earlier_Times) which starts a battle over.

If I use Thought Peak on an enemy to fill out it's Monster List entry then use Earlier Times to reset the battle, will that reset the enemy's Monster List entry too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you use Thought Peak on an enemy then reset the battle with Earlier Times, the game resets any Monster List entries completed during the fight.